# How do I get the value of user inputted data?

Tags: backbone.js

Say I have a website with some fields that I want to run some calculations on. I have a quantity input, and in my backbone.js View I bound the "change" event to this input.

How do I get the value of the changes to the input field?

I found this method (below) to get the value, but it feels wrong since I have to know the element ID again in my function. I couldn't do this with a class, for example.

```js
window.Calculations = Backbone.View.extend({

    (...)

    events: {
        'change input#quantity': 'changeQuantity'
    },


    changeQuantity: function() {
        var val = $(this.el).find('input#quantity').val();
        this.model.set({'quantity': val});
    }

});
```

And in the HTML:

```js
<input type="text" id="quantity" value="<%= quantity %>">
```

Am I approaching this correctly? Is there a variable that access the object that was changed? I know that $(this.el) isn't it, it's just the container.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

jQuery sends an `event` object to your function `changeQuantity`.  With it, you can retrieve the changed input.

```
window.Calculations = Backbone.View.extend({

    //(...)

    events: {
        'change input#quantity': 'changeQuantity'
    },


    changeQuantity: function(e) {
        var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        this.model.set({'quantity': val});
    }

});
```

I created a jsfiddle as an example : http://jsfiddle.net/tz3XS/138/

Comment: Thank you, that works! I wonder why I don't see it in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: actually, because this is not backbone,  all backbone does is bind the function to the element's event after rendered. it is jQuery that passes the arguments to the callback function, and i bet this is well documented in the jQuery documentation. however, adding a line referencing these jquery Documentation pages can't hurt, you are right on that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `target` of the event, which you can fetch as argument of the callback function.
(i had to add some code myself to make it work, since you didn't give us the model code i substituted it with window.CalcModel (an empty model))

```
window.CalcModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Calculations = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'change input#quantity': 'changeQuantity'
    },

    initialize: function() {

    },

    changeQuantity: function(evt) {
        var val = $(evt.target).val();
        this.model.set({'quantity': val});
        $(this.el).find('#result').text('new value = ' + val);
    },

    render: function() {

    }

});
```

var c = new window.Calculations({ model: new CalcModel(), el: '#myView' });

example
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/uxHLL/